# Updating TypeScript Definition for a 3rd Party Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to temporarily update the type definitions for `ngx-filepond` to include the `removeFiles(...)` method in an Angular 9.x application.  The method works if you invoke it, but throws a Type error:

```
Property 'removeFiles' does not exist on type 'FilePondComponent'.
```

I've added a `/types` folder to the root of the project and added a `/ngx-filepond/index.d.ts` file, as well as, included it in the `tsconfig.json` under `typeRoots`.

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "types",
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Removed for brevity
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
  // Removed for brevity
}
```

I want to do something like this to add the method `removeFiles` to the typings, but this won't work since `FilePondComponent` is already declared.

```js
import 'ngx-filepond/filepond.component';

declare module 'ngx-filepond/filepond.component' {
  export class FilePondComponent {
    public removeFiles(query: any): void;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to have the typings merge similar to interfaces in TypeScript?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you could avoid the ts error by using bracket notation: `this["removeFiles"](arguments)` or `filePondComponentReference["removeFiles"](arguments)`. Not pretty, but maybe as pretty as overriding the typings for a package class that you don't "own." Given that it isn't your class, it would make sense to check for the method's existence before calling via bracket notation.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBaker